# Does the use of cannabis affect the ability to recall dreams?

Tags: memory, dreams, drugs

Will cannabis be a negative factor in the ability to recall dreams from waking up.

How do the cannabinoids affect you when in a dreaming state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current research tells us that **yes**, cannabis will affect the ability to recall dreams. As for the negative - positive outcomes, it seems to be subjective.

One of the few researchers in this field, Hans Hamburger says:

> “By smoking weed, you suppress the REM sleep, and with that you also
>   suppress a lot of important functions of that REM sleep. One of those
>   functions is reliving the things you have experienced and coming to
>   terms with them, as it were. Processing all kinds of psychological
>   influences is something you do in REM sleep.
>
> You also anticipate the things that will happen the next day or the
>   days after that. While you’re sleeping, you already consider those and
>   make decisions in advance.” – Hamburger

You can find more of his publications here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=Hans%20Hamburger